# dipsose() Being called at same time as initState()

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm porting a offline Flutter game to online and the only difference in the code is that the new online code where the problem occurs has a active StreamSubscription being listened to. I can't find anything online other than 1 issue saying this is a bug.. any ideas on why `dipose()` is being called on the initial build?

```
class _OnlineSequenceState extends State<OnlineSequence> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

 //variable initialization would be here

 @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();

    //setup gameRef
    gameRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('sequence').child(widget.gameID);

    //glow animation init
    _setupGlowAnimtation();

    //init sounds
     _initSounds();

    //setup player and card objects and create a stream
    _setupGame();   
  }

 @override
 void dispose(){
    print('disposing'); //prints on the widget being built for the first time
    gameDataStream.cancel();
    _animation.removeListener(() {});
    _animationController.stop();
    pool.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  _setupGlowAnimtation() {
    _animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1300));
    _animationController.repeat(reverse: true);
    _animation = Tween(begin: 1.0, end: 6.4).animate(_animationController)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
    }

   _initSounds() async {
     drawSound = await pool.load(await rootBundle.load('lib/assets/sounds/draw.wav'));
     playCardSound = await (pool.load(await rootBundle.load('lib/assets/sounds/playcard.wav')));
     shuffleSound = await (pool.load(await rootBundle.load('lib/assets/sounds/shuffle.wav')));
     pool.play(shuffleSound);
   }

  ...
```

Comment: Are you doing `Navigator.of(context).pop()` anywhere in your `build`?

Comment: Only in a  `onTap : (){}` of a exit button.

Comment: @enzo thankyou I fixed it due to your comment making me think of something else. It turns out the problem was in the prior lobby page. The host of the game would load the game screen twice instead of once, resulting in this bug and weird dispose behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error turned out to actually be in the prior lobby screen. The host of the game would navigate to in-game screen twice instead of once causing weird `dispose()` behavior. Once I fixed the double navigation the issue went away.